# Best way to share sensitive data over AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Suppose you have to share data with a third party over the internet and the data is stored in AWS. What would be the most secure and easy way to do this?

Since sending mail is not very secure, i thought of the solution of creating a S3 bucket and run a SFTP server (with AWS Family) on it. Is there a better solution in AWS to achieve this?

Comment: Where is the data stored? (For example, is it in Amazon S3, or a database, or somewhere else?) How many users would be accessing it? Does it need to be automated, or would the access be performed manually? Do the other people have their own AWS Account? Please tell us more!

Comment: Data is stored in S3. Only a fuew users. It needs to be automated. No, they do not have their own account, but probably could get one.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you want to "share data" and where that data resides.

Let's say you have an object in Amazon S3 that you would like to make available. There are several options for sharing access:

- You could create an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to a private object. This is similar to storing something in DropBox and using the "Get Link" command to obtain a special URL that provides access to the object.
- If the other people have their own AWS Account, you could share a specific bucket or an object with them. This has the benefit that you could put objects in a bucket and they can retrieve any of them whenever they wish.
- You could write a web application that requires users to authenticate and then gives them the ability to access objects in Amazon S3. This would be similar to a photo-sharing website, where people login and can access/share photos. You would be responsible for writing this application and managing the authentication.

**Update**

Based on the information you provided (S3, few users, automated), the easiest method would probably be to have the other users sign-up to AWS or provide them with IAM access credentials from your own AWS Account (not recommended if you have large numbers of such users).

You can grant permission for them to access your data and they could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access/download the data. This can be automated with the `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 sync` commands.

Comment: What would be the best way, if they cannot have AWS Accounts? I have seen SFTP, but it is very costly (230$ a months) and you cant do presigned, because it would lack security.

Comment: You could provide credentials from your account, with access limited to the desired bucket/files. They could use the AWS CLI to access the files.